# How to remove padding or margin in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, vuetify.js

[The doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing) tells me I can use a helper class to change padding/margin. I want to remove padding from an input field, so the class I need is `pa-0` (`{property}{direction}-{size}`):

```
<v-text-field v-model="mon" pa-0 solo></v-text-field>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgpfhn8m/1489/) here

Doesn't work. Any idea?

EDIT: I realise I obtain a completely different markup in my JSFiddle compared to my local setup, which compounds my confusion:

Markup generated by Vuetify locally (here I want to remove vertical padding inside the `<input>` element and horizontal padding on `<div class="v-input__slot">` element):

```
<div class="v-input v-text-field v-text-field--enclosed v-text-field--outline v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light">
  <div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot" style="">
      <div class="v-text-field__slot">
        <input type="text" pa-0="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
      <div class="v-messages theme--light">
        <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Markup generated by Vuetify on JSFiddle using the exact same line of Vuetify code (`<v-text-field v-model="mon" pa-0 outline></v-text-field>`):

```
<div class="input-group input-group--text-field">
  <div class="input-group__input">
    <input outline="" pa-0="" tabindex="0" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group__details">
    <div class="input-group__messages"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The lack of examples throughout the docs REALLY doesn't help.

Comment: could you provide a pen?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with a demo

Comment: you're talking about the padding inside or outside of the text-field?

Comment: I edited my question again: the markup on JSFiddle and on my local setup are completely different... On my local setup, I want to remove vertical padding inside the `<input>` element and horizontal padding on `<div class="v-input__slot">` element.

Comment: it's not attribute, but class: `class="pa-0 ma-0"`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that at some point locally but now I see it works fine on my JSFiddle. Any idea why it doesn't change anything on my local setup, and perhaps by the same token, why the two markups are totally different?

Comment: Just noticed your fiddle is using vuetify version `0.14`, lol, that's really old version and that's why markup is different. So perhaps use [another template](https://template.vuetifyjs.com) for further testing

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use [spacing helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/spacing#how-it-works):

`class="ma-0"` removes margins
`class="pa-0"` removes padding
`class="ma-0 pa-0"` removes both

Note that these are also props but only for some (grid) components so for example:
`<v-text-field class="pa-0"></v-text-field>`  will work,
and `<v-text-field pa-0></v-text-field>` will not work.

Classes are added on top-level element so if in some components you can't remove child-element(s) spacing with these classes, then likely you need to target relevant elements with CSS.

---

To avoid using `!important`, add custom class on the component and inspect element which you want to edit and then check what's used for targeting it - for example `.v-input__slot` (we only need highlighted target):

[image]

Then replace it like so (`custom-text-field` is arbitrary custom class applied to the component)

```
.custom-text-field.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__slot {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: But even `<v-text-field class="pa-0"><v-text-field>` doesn't work: https://codepen.io/Draikin1/pen/jQZqYV. There is really no way to remove these paddings/margins without overriding manually? :/

Comment: @drake035 Can you be more specific which ones you want removed? With classes most likely no, but perhaps you want to add `single-line` property so it's centered? [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aQqZVg). (It was not clear to me what your goal was because vuetify versions in reproductions did not match)

Comment: I want to remove vertical padding inside the `<input>` element and horizontal padding on `<div class="v-input__slot">`. Currently I'm doing it with super ugly !important CSS rules on `.v-input__slot { ... }` and `input { ... }` but I'm hoping there's some more decent solution available...

Comment: @drake035 I don't think there are classes (at least not now) to remove those paddings because it's probably not common use-case to remove those specific paddings (for example it's probably not common design to have cursor hugging the left border which is apparently what you are trying to do). Thus it's nothing weird about having to use your own CSS from time to time. Tho you probably want to add custom class to that v-text-field and then target CSS specific to that class children so there are no side effects e.g. `.custom-text-field .v-input__slot` (unless you want it globally ofc).

Comment: @drake035 Btw, no need for `!important` if you target it properly e.g. `.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__slot`.

Comment: thanks but even using custom class exactly like that (`.custom-text-field .v-input__slot`), I still need to use `!important`. It looks like most if not all custom styles must carry `!important` with Vuetify. That's really not ideal :(

Answer (score 59):

Use the `hide-details` option: `<v-text-field hide-details></v-text-field>` to remove the bottom margin, that appears because of the details field used to display details, if available.

Comment: This also works for vuetify 3.

Comment: In case you need to show the details when there are any errors you can use: hide-details="auto"

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer for Vue3**

The accepted answer requires you to include the whole tree like:

`.custom-text-field.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__slot {padding: 0;}`

Vue does have a easier method available for this, called [deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements).

Instead of the code snippet above it would look like this in **Vue2** :

`.custom-text-field /deep/ .v-input__slot { padding: 0; }`

In **Vue3** it would look like this for a v-text-field (note the different class).

`.custom-text-field /deep/ .v-field__input { padding: 0; }`