# How to remove container margin in vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to remove margin left and right from `v-container` so I add `pa-0` class.

Also I need to have a space between each element so I using `grid-list-sm`.

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm class="pa-0">
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="i in 6" :key="i" xs4>
          <img :src="`https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/${i + 20}.jpg`" class="image" alt="lorem" width="100%" height="100%">
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The problem is `grid-list-sm` is reducing size to `4px` in `<v-layout row wrap>` because margin `-2px`. and makes the v-layout to be widther than his parent.

**I do not want to use `overflow-x:hidden`. I just want the elements to align correctly.**

So, how I can solve this problem? (without workaround)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355605/how-to-remove-padding-or-margin-in-vuetify/53399834#53399834

Comment: No. please read my question.

Comment: You said that you wanted to remove margins, but used "pa-0" which is for paddings. Provide codepen?

Comment: But when I using pa-0 class like the link you provide, the grid-list-sm makes the v-layout widther like I explain in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the attribute in the class where you are using it, as follows, it is overwritten in the css file of your class, or you can make a css file with the code and include it in each class where you need it

```
.row{
     margin-right: 0px
}
```