# How to remove padding from v-select component in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

[how to remove padding from v-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHtoM.png)

[This is my code]

```
<v-select
  :items="cities"
  class="select--menu"
  label="Solo field"
  solo
  hide-details
  hide-selected
  dense
  append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
  prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker-outline"
></v-select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove padding or margin in Vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355605/how-to-remove-padding-or-margin-in-vuetify)

Comment: @skobaljic No, it does not

Comment: `.v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed .v-text-field__details, .v-text-field.v-text-field--enclosed:not(.v-text-field--rounded)>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot {
    padding: 0 12px;
}
`

change this in your styling file!

Comment: @skobaljic still not working

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      cities: [1,2,3]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-select .v-input__slot {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-select
          :items="cities"
          class="select--menu my-select"
          label="without padding"
          solo
          hide-details
          hide-selected
          dense
          append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
          prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker-outline"
        ></v-select>
      </v-container>
      <v-container>
        <v-select
          :items="cities"
          class="select--menu"
          label="with padding"
          solo
          hide-details
          hide-selected
          dense
          append-icon="mdi-chevron-down"
          prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker-outline"
        ></v-select>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, vuetify uses its own custom components.
To enter the vue components styling from a parent component, you need to use vues *deep-selector*: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-vue-deep-css-selector

Depending on which version you use, it is `>>>`, `::v-deep` or even `:v-deep()`.